# An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have this function

```
 public static List<Product> GetProductsByStoreID(int? StoreID, ProductLocation? location , string search = "", string barcode = "", string Relations = "no")
        {
            using (DbContext Context = new DbContext())
            {
                string Barcode = "";//.TrimStart('0');
                if (Barcode.IndexOf("d") == 0)
                {
                  Barcode=  barcode.Split('d')[1];
                }
                else
                {
                    Barcode = barcode;
                }
                IQueryable<Product> products = Context.Products.Include(p => p.PosOrderDetail);
                foreach (string item in GetRelations(Relations))
                {
                    products = products.Include(item);
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Barcode))
                    products = products.Where(p => p.Barcode.Contains(Barcode));

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
                    products = products.Where(p => p.Item.ItemName.Contains(search) || p.Description.Contains(search));
                if ( location != null)
                    products = products.Where(d => d.ProductLocation == (int)location);
                if (StoreID != null)
                    products = products.Where(d => d.StoreID == StoreID );

                if (products.Count() > 0)
                    return products.ToList();
                else
                    return null;
            }
        }
```

it gives me the exception in `return products.ToList();`

> An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Data is very huge because when I filter with another property in 
`IQueryable<Product> products = Context.Products.Include(p => p.weight );`

it works fine
please help

Answer (score 1):

Entity framework keeps an additional copy of data for change tracking , 
If you really want to load very large set of data in to memory try to load the Data with "AsNoTracking()" option which tells EF not to keep the second copy

Context.products.AsNoTracking().ToList()